# Advanced Conditional Types - Infer syntax

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

## Intro

I've been playing around with some advanced features of TS and found some cool things you can do. One cool thing that caught my eye was extracting all the types of each element in an array. However the syntax in this particular example I find confusing.

The most confusing part of the two samples I have highlighted directly below this comment and are present in both examples with a slight variation.

**Problematic line**

```js
T extends (infer U)[]
```

**Example 1**

```js
type ArrayTypes<T> = 
    T extends (infer U)[]
    ? U
    : never

let arr = [1, "2", []];
type test = ArrayTypes<typeof arr> // type test = string | number | any[]
```

**Example 2**

```js
type ArrayTypes<T> = 
    T extends (infer U)
    ? U
    : never

let arr = [1, "2", []];
type test = ArrayTypes<typeof arr> // type test = (string | number | any[])[]
```

## Question

Now, I understand generics ( for the most part ) and so I understand what **T** represents and I also understand what **extends** does ( for the most part ). I also understand that **U** can be used to **infer** a type when ever a generic type **could** be used.

What i don't get specifically is what and how the parenthesis and the square brackets are doing in both examples. I would greatly appreciate a full breakdown. If you need to explain more about how infer or extends work, feel free but like i said, I think i get those concepts... perhaps not. One thing that is really confusing is if i take the **()** / parenthesis away then it alls screws up. why is that?

Am i correct in thinking the following assumptions?

1. behind the scenes, In the type space, parentheses are a stricter way of defining a union type? and hence typescript will turn the following

```js
type test2 = string | number
```

into

```js
type test2 = ( string | number )
```

Notice the parentheses.

2. (infer U) is saying - define a new union type, but infer it and assign it to U. it is also makes up the types of an array?

```
T extends (infer U)[]
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Parentheses** in types are just for grouping and to resolve ambiguities; they do not modify the type that they surround.  For example, given the types

```
type A = { a: 1, c: 3 };
type B = { b: 2, c: 3 };
```

Then what does this type resolve to?

```
type Z = keyof A | B; // ??
```

With parentheses you can be explicit about how you mean for that to be interpreted:

```
type X = (keyof A) | B; // "a" | "c" | B
type Y = keyof (A | B); // "c"
```

It turns out that `keyof` binds more tightly to `A` than the union operator `|` does, so `Z` is equivalent to `X`... so if you mean `Y` you need those parentheses.

The (increasingly outdated) [TypeScript Specification document](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#38-specifying-types) says:

> Parentheses are required around union, intersection, function, or constructor types when they are used as array element types; around union, function, or constructor types in intersection types; and around function or constructor types in union types.

When in doubt, add parentheses.

---

**Square brackets** in types actually have a variety of different meanings:

- When a type `T` is immediately followed by a pair of *empty* square brackets, it means an *array* whose elements are of type `T`, and is equivalent to `Array<T>`.  So `{a: string}[]` is an array whose elements are of type `{a: string}`, and is equivalent to `Array<{a: string}>`.  (Similarly, if such a type is immediately preceded by the `readonly` modifier, like `readonly T[]`, then it is equivalent to `ReadonlyArray<T>`.)
- When a type `T` is immediately followed by another type `U` encased in square brackets, (i.e., `T[U]`)... the brackets are *not empty*, it means you are [looking up or indexing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) the type of the property of `T` whose key is of type `U`.  So `{a: string}["a"]` is the type of the `a` property of `{a: string}`... namely, `string`.  And `Array<boolean>[number]` is the type you get when you index into an `Array<boolean>` with a `number` key... namely `boolean`.
- When square brackets contain a comma-delimited list of zero or more types like `[]` or `[T]` or `[T,U]` or `[T,U,V]`, etc., (and if it's zero or one you need to be careful not to confuse it for the array or lookup notation above), then you are specifying a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) type, an array with a fixed number of possibly differently-typed elements in a fixed order.  Tuple types can also be preceded with `readonly` to make [readonly tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#readonly-tuples), and there are other fun things going on with tuples, like [rest and optional elements in tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions) and [variadic tuple types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39094), so `readonly [0, ...[1, 2, 3], 4?, ...[5?, 6?, 7?], ...8[]]` is a valid TS type (in TS4.0+).

---

Armed with that, let's look at these examples:

```
type ArrayTypes<T> = 
    T extends (infer U)[]
    ? U
    : never
```

This is saying: given a type `T`, if it extends some array type `U[]` where `U` is to be inferred, then return `U`, otherwise return `never`. The `infer` needs to attach to `U`.  For whatever reason, `[]` binds more tightly than `infer`, and so `T extends infer U[]` would be interpreted as `T extends infer (U[])`... which is invalid because you can only `infer` a new type variable, not a function of such a variable.  That's why you need the parentheses.

```
let arr = [1, "2", []];
type test = ArrayTypes<typeof arr> // type test = string | number | never[]
```

That makes sense, right?  `arr` is inferred to be of type `Array<string | number | Array<never>>` or the equivalent `(string | number | never[])[]`, and thus `ArrayTypes<typeof arr>` infers `U` to be `string | number | never[]` and that's what you get.  (Note that the value `[]` is inferred as type `never[]` in the TS version I'm using and not `any[]`).

Also note, as an aside, that the lookup type above with a `number` key does the same thing without needing `infer`:

```
type ArrayTypes<T> = T extends any[] ? T[number]: never;
```

---

Next example:

```
type ArrayTypes<T> = 
    T extends (infer U)
    ? U
    : never
```

Here the parentheses aren't necessary because there is no ambiguity.  You could write `T extends infer U ? U : never`.  This means: given a type `T` that extends some inferred type `U`, return `U`; otherwise return `never`.  But this seems a bit silly, since `U` will always be inferred to be `T`, and thus `ArrayTypes<T>` will always be `T`, no matter what:

```
let arr = [1, "2", []];
type test = ArrayTypes<typeof arr> // type test = (string | number | never[])[]
```

The type `test` is going to be just the same as `typeof arr`, which is `Array<string | number | Array<never>>`, or equivalently, `(string | number | never[])[]`.

---

I hope that clarifies things for you.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUCGAuKBGANFAxpgMxQC+A3AFCiRQBCCyUARpgEx6FQkXXjQAtRgGsIIAPYAzWFAA+9clAD0SqAH41fWgA1GAClETpMAJRyFy1QCJUV81fx35dLdACaIsVKh64zk4oqUA5WlFCUAHaoALYQAM5gqPjQAKIAHjFgADYQAPIR0EhhUCU00DAAThWoIAAq-HEAPLUAfIy1UBBpwBARACZxPgCWEZIQFVAAqiYA2gC66lNQmAUAbuNUJSU5wGhVjDO4wWxWePNzm1tlUD1xu4iV1XUNjWXeqFVtQde391B3FRGAHNzBEAK7RZjjUEQdYVebhUiRGLxRLJKDpfIQAAK4hGwAAYkN1shiqV+LAqjV6pAmq12p1ur0BmgIiAEWooLUZuDIeMFitYRsyVAdnsJohDngrCcznMLiKfvE-o9qS83tIPhUvqolXdGADgaCIVCJvI1uN5pQkVFYgkkqk0rUAO7iUlbG4U1XPWnNNqIDpdHr9QZ6EZjCbTRaTZZQC0VEVirUHI4y05Qc6Xcm0X6Mb00+KvfjvT6WT055X6Q0REHmk3Q81C+FzWZza1AA)

Comment: Thanks so much for your response that was like someone explaining the entire universe in one go ( enlightening ). :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. This helped me a lot: "It turns out that keyof binds more tightly to A than the union operator | does". The statement makes everything much clearer.